# Return Key Val Pair from Arrow function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to return a key val pair from a `filter` based on the presence of `__`

Got this:

```
function trigger() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ranges = ss.getNamedRanges();
  const rangeNames = ranges.map(range => range.getName());

  let triggers = {};
  triggers = rangeNames.filter(name => {
                               if (name.indexOf("__")>-1) {const val = ss.getRangeByName(name).getValue(); 
                                                          
                                                           triggers.name = val
                                                           return triggers;
                                                          }
});

console.log(triggers);

}
```

But it just seems to return `name`. Any help would be gratefully received

Comment: You're declaring `triggers` as an object, but then reassigning it to the return value of `filter ` in the next line.

Comment: Hmm. I assumed that I could just remove the return line but that doesn't work either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `filter` function of an array accepts a function that just should return and false.
Maybe what can work for you is use the reduce method.

```
 let triggers = {};
 triggers = rangeNames.reduce( (acc, curr)=>{
      if (curr.indexOf("__")>-1){
         acc[curr] = ss.getRangeByName(curr).getValue();
      }
      return triggers;
 }, triggers );
```

Or if you don't mind to use that `ranges` in other place inside that function
you can `reduce` the "namedRanges" directly

```
function trigger() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const triggers = ss.getNamedRanges().reduce( (acc,curr)=>{
           if (curr.getName().indexOf("__")>-1) {
                     acc[curr.getName()]=curr.getValue();
           }
           return acc;
                                       
  }, {});

  console.log(triggers);

}
```

Comment: @jmtalam thanks. That got it although I did need to change `acc[curr.getName()]=curr.getValue()` to `acc[curr.getName()]=curr.getRange().getValue()`

Comment: This would be my thought too. You can make the check for `__` a little more readable with `curr.includes('__')`